# Teamfoundationserver branching not working in any form

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have tried branching in a very simple sample project and it worked.  Now I want to branch a real life project and it is simply not working.

When I try to branch the whole team project, tfs tells ask for a destination. If I choose a new destination it tells me, that the destination does not exist. If I create a new one and point to it, it tells me that the folder already exists.

When I try to branch the team project into a sub-folder within the team project it tells me that this procedure cant be done, fair enough.

But when I try to branch a single project within the team project to another sub-folder it tells me that there was no correct mapping ('keine passende Zuordnung', in German I don't know the exact English error message).

Any help on this is very appreciated. I fail to see, what I do differently here, then I did before in my test project.

Edit: As suggested I post an image of my project structure. The upper folder is my actuall project which I have converted from a teamproject to a branch. The second on is the destination folder which is empty.
[image: My project structure]

Answer (score 1):

When branching a whole team project (`$/ProjectName`), you either need to use the New Project Wizard to create a new project and specify that it should branch from your current project.

When branching a sub-folder of your team project, that should work, unless a parent of that sub-folder is marked as a branch root, in which case there is no location to branch to.

Any folder that either holds a branch root as a child, or has abranch root as a parent cannot be used to create a new branch:

[image]

On the commandline try running `tf branches .` from the folder that you want to branch (to see if it is part of a branch) and from the folder you want to branch to. If the target folder is already under a branch, you can't branch to it. You might need to use the [<kbd>Convert to Folder</kbd>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx) option in the Source control explorer to allow branches to be created there.

It looks like you've already created the target folder, and the target folder is already a branch. You haven't described how that came to be, if it's a result from a Branch action on the source folder, then instead of choosing <kbd>Branch</kbd> pick <kbd>Merge</kbd> instead.

If there is no relationship between the two folders then it won't be pre-populated in the list of possible merge targets. If you're using Visual Studio 2013 you can enter the path manually and TFS will create the relationship by doing a baseless merge. If you're using an older version of Visual Studio you may need to create this relationship from the commandline:

> `tf merge  "$/TeamProject/Machinenzustandsanzeige" "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" /baseless /recursive /collection:{uri}`

You can also destroy the target branch that you've created using the commandline and then re-attempt the branch, which should then succeed.

> `tf destroy "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" /recursive /collection:{uri}`
>
> `tf branch  "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige;T" "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" /recursive  /collection:{uri}`
>
> `tf checkin "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" /recursive /collection:{uri}`

In case the workspace isn't setup correctly yet you can either do it [through the UI using the steps outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx#edit) or from the commandline using:

> `tf workfold /map "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" c:\path\where\you\want\it`

followed by:

> `tf get "$/teamproject/Machinenzustandsanzeige NC-Prä" /recursive`

to effectuate the addition of the folder.

There is a very slim chance that the a-umlaut is causing the issue. Have you tried a path without special characters?

What you want to achieve is a standard operation and TFVC supports it, but somehow you ended up in a situation that is non-default. Even in such a situation you can get it fixed, but you might need to resort to advanced features such as `/baseless` or `/force` or `tf destroy` which are not available from the UI.

Comment: To further improve the answer it would be helpful if you could post a screenshot/textual representation of your project structure and from where you want to branch to where.

Comment: I put an image in my initial post. But since noone else is answering this seems to be broken. My structure is far from being complicated. If TFS cant do THIS SIMPLE TASK, we will complety forget about creating brances, and look for anohter solution. It is SIMPLY IMPOSSIBLE FOR ME to spend my worktime in this!!!!!!!

Comment: This is not broken. Your structure is pretty simple, but there seems to be an incorrect order to the actions which brought you in your current situation. I added some 'advanced' commands that may get you out of there. If you want additional support, I might have time to chat later.

Comment: It sounds like the workspace mappings are not there for the folder being branched to. Can you show your workspace mapping as well?

Comment: Added some guidance to setup workspaces. See also: Shttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx#edit